# Overriden method calls original method declared in extension (category) in swift?

Tags: swift, overriding, extension-methods, categories, method-call

My code:

```
extension UIViewController {
    @IBAction func someFunc() {
        ...
    }
}

class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction override func someFunc() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can `CustomViewController.someFunc()` call `UIViewController.someFunc()`?

There are similar questions but my is different. **NOTE:** the original method is declared in extension not parent class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to call `super.someFunc()`.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction override func someFunc() {
        // Call super method
        super.someFunc()
        // Do override specific stuff
        ...
    }
}
```

P.S.: be aware that you forgot to inherit from `UIViewController` in your example.

Comment: Read the question again. My question is not a duplicate of other questions about inheritance. If it is not possible to call the overriden extension method then write about it please. Otherwise it is not an answer

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov it doesn't method where the original method is declared. However, the method must be inherited, otherwise there's no overriding taking place. So is your `CustomViewController` supposed to be a subclass of `UIViewController` or not? You don't actually mention anything about inheritance, but your code only makes sense and compiles when inheritance takes place, so rather refine your question than say I misread it :)

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: If CustomViewController does not inherit from UIViewController then in what sense does it “override” a method from that class?

Comment: @DávidPásztor @MartinR sorry, missed it. Thanks. But `You last voted on this answer 17 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`